# How to calculate inner product between vector $xx^T$ and matrix $A^TA$?

Tags: inner-products

If $\langle A,B\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij}$, how do I solve

$$\langle xx^T,A^TA\rangle$$?

Is there a shortcut for doing this? or should I expand each entry and do the inner product?

I got $\|Ax\|^2_2$, but wondering if there is any other ways to do it.

Comment: I changed $<A,B>=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij}$ to $\langle A,B\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij}.$ That is standard and proper MathJax (and LaTeX) usage. $$\begin{align} \text{wrong: } & <A,B>=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij} \\ {} \\ \text{right: } & \langle A,B\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_{ij} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to find a cleaner formula than $\|Ax\|_2^2.$

You can derive it in a coordinate-free manner by using the formula for Frobenius product in terms of trace:
$$A:B = \operatorname{tr}(A^TB).$$
So then
$$xx^T : A^TA = \operatorname{tr}(xx^TA^TA) = \operatorname{tr}(x^TA^TAx) = (Ax) : (Ax) = \|Ax\|^2_2$$
where the key second step uses invariance of trace under cyclic permutations.

Comment: Does it apply to inner product between two vectors, i.e., for $<xx^T,yy^T>$, $xx^T : yy^T = tr(xx^Tyy^T) = tr(x^Tyy^Tx) =(y^Tx):(y^Tx) = (y^Tx)^2 $?

Comment: @JaydenRice Sure, that works.